# Error: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plugin: Deploying Gstreamer plugins with QML application

Tags: qt, deployment, qml, gstreamer

I am trying to create a package for a QML application which plays both audio and video and i'm stuck at GStreamer plugins. I use `cqtdeployer` to create this distribution package. This tool beautifully gathers the libraries and (qml)plugins that the executable needs. However, it cannot detect some libraries such as GStreamer and its plugins even if I increase the recursive depth.

If i install `gstreamer1.0-libav` from `apt` video and audio do play. However, I will be deploying this package offline.

I've checked the contents of this package https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gstreamer1.0-libav and the only shared library it consists is `libgstlibav.so`, and I also copied it to my `lib/` folder. Also installed `gstreamer1.0-plugins-base` on my development environment and copied everything under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/` to my application's `lib/` folder as well.

When I try and run the software on a virtual machine audio alone plays, however, the video does not play and gives the following error:
`Warning: "No decoder available for type 'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)main, codec_data..` etc.

Similar warning for audio as well when I attempt to play the video: `"Warning: No decoder available for 'audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4..` etc. But i suppose this is about video's playback audio. Because as I said, i can play audio alone.

Thanks for any help in advance. I can share an ugly list of libraries that I ship with my software if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/running.html?gi-language=c. Specifically `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` you can set a directory to scan for plugins.

Note that plugins really are plugins. They are scanned and run at time. That is also the reason no qtdeploy script etc can detect potential missing plugins. The use of plugins is being done by names, not bt actually linking them to the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try and let you know.

Comment: P.S. If you want to do that with code, check out `GstRegistry` and it's functions.

Comment: I faced lots of more problems and got my package ready. Your answer was very helpful along the way. Thank you again.

Comment: It's a bit tricky to figure where plugins have been installed in order to supply them on that environment variable. E.g. I seem to have `apt` plugin packages installed ("good", "bad", and "ugly" whatever this subdivision means in gstreamer packages) but the directories that `whereis` gives me for them don't seem to include anything but two executables. I wonder for example, which packages are plugins for mp4 and avi codecs included in. Made that a [separate platform specific question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369800/how-to-handle-gstreamer-missing-codecs).